# Python27 qpid: ImportError: No module named _cproton

Tags: python, amqp, qpid

I try to execute the below code but unfortunately I am getting the following error. Any      suggestions are really appreciated.

I have the following files in c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
1) cproton.py
2) proton.py
3) _cproton.so

```
import sys
from cproton import *
from proton import *

#This code is for initiating the AMQP messenger
amqpmng = Messenger()
amqpmng._set_timeout(2000L) #Set timeout for sending and receiving at 2000 ms
address = "amqps://<<user>>:<<password>>@<<namespace>>.servicebus.windows.net/<<queue>>" 

#This code is for creating messages
msg = Message()
msg.subject = "This is a testmessage"
msg.body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."

#This code is for sending messages
try:
    msg.address = address
    amqpmng.put(msg)
    amqpmng.send()
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e, "Waited for 2s to send messages, nothing send, connection timed out"

amqpmng.stop();

#This code is for receiving messages
amqpmng.subscribe(address)
amqpmng.start()
try:
    amqpmng.recv(1) #receive exactly 1 message (you can enter any value)
    msg = Message()
    while amqpmng.incoming > 0:
        amqpmng.get(msg)
        print(msg.body)
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e, "Waited for 2s to receive messages, nothing received, connection timed out"

amqpmng.stop()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "receiv.py", line 2, in <module> from cproton import *

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cproton.py", line 29, in <module>
           _cproton = swig_import_helper()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cproton.py", line 21, in swig_import_helpe
           r

    import _cproton

    ImportError: No module named _cproton
```

Answer (score 2):

An `.so` file is a dynamic link library for use on UNIX systems. It will not work on Windows.

Unless you can find a pre-built Windows binary, you are going to have to compile it yourself. You can find build instructions [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/qpid/proton/trunk/README?revision=1583443&view=markup).

Answer (score 1):

Hey you are using my code great :).
Try to debug what is wrong.
Can you change these lines in cproton.py.

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info >= (2,6,0):
    def swig_import_helper():
        from os.path import dirname
        import imp
        fp = None
        try:
            fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_cproton', [dirname(__file__)])
            print fp #<-- manually added code
            print pathname #<-- manually added code
            print description #<-- manually added code
        except ImportError:
            import _cproton
            return _cproton
        if fp is not None:
            try:
                _mod = imp.load_module('_cproton', fp, pathname, description)
            finally:
                fp.close()
            return _mod
    _cproton = swig_import_helper()
    del swig_import_helper
else:
    import _cproton
del version_info
```

I think that python is searching in the wrong directories.
It is just a guess.
Let me know the output.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved this issue myself. I have followed the same steps in the below link and did the setup in debian linux. Now its working fine.    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn235560.aspx